# What is this tree/bush with thorns and small blue solid fruits?

Tags: identification, trees, shrubs, thorns

There's a tree in our yard of which we do not know it's name. In other parts of the yard it grows more like a bush. It has thorns and grows small solid fruits that turn dark blue when ripe. On the picture attached one fruit still looks green. Question is: what is our tree-bush's sort?

[image: Tree]

[image: Leaves2]

Comment: too hard to tell from that distance. take pictures of the leaves, and fruit.

Comment: I edited it, the upload went wrong

Comment: What do individual leaves look like?

Comment: I improved the close up picture

Comment: Also, could you give us a bit more info on where you are/what climate it is growing in?

Comment: It's in Southern France.

Comment: Can you give us a closer picture of the main trunk and its bark?

Comment: A picture of the fruit pit should be telling, too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect it may be Prunus spinosa, commonly known as Sloe - should have had creamy white flowers in Spring, and does have stiff, thorny branches. If left unpruned will reach about 16 feet in height, but is often seen as a bush or shrub. If it is, and you drink gin, time to make sloe gin! More info here

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prunus_spinosa#Description

Answer (score 3):

It looks to me like a plum tree—probably a dwarf. It's possibly a Stanley prune plum, or a similar variety. We've had plum trees and I've seen several besides, and that's what it looks like to me, based on the close-up picture with the small branch and fruit.

Bamboo's suspicion sounds like a good one to me, though.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a bullace.fruits ripen after a frost. They make good jam.